# supplies foreach error in my codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: daftar_user

Filename: views/daftar_user.php

Line Number: 17

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/daftar_user.php

Line Number: 17

Nik Nama    Tempat Lahir    Tanggal Lahir   Umur    Status  Jenis Kelamin   alamat
Nik Nama    Tempat Lahir    Tanggal Lahir   Umur    Status  Jenis Kelamin   alamat



#controller
  function penduduk()
  {
    $this->load->view('main');
  }

  function simpan_penduduk()
  {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->simpan_penduduk();   
  }

  function user()
  {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data['judul']= 'menampilkan data penduduk';
    $data['daftar_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_all();
    $this->load->view('daftar_user', $data);
  }
}

#user_model.php

<?php
        /**
         * 
         */
        class User_model extends CI_Model {

            function simpan_penduduk() 
            {
                $simpan_data=array(
                'no_kk'       => $this->input->post('no_kk'),
                'nik'         => $this->input->post('nik'),
                'nama'        => $this->input->post('nama'),
                'tempat_lahir'    => $this->input->post('tempat_lahirt'), 
                'tanggal_lahir'   => $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'),
                'umur'        => $this->input->post('umur'),
                'status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
                'jenis_kelamin'   => $this->input->post('jenis_kelamin'),
                'alamat'      => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                );
                $simpan = $this->db->insert('penduduk', $simpan_data);
                return $simpan;            
            }

            function get_user_all()
            {
                $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM penduduk ORDER BY nik DESC");
                return $query->result(); 
            }
        }

    ?>

#daftar_user.php

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nik</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Tempat Lahir</th>
            <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
        <th>Umur</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
            <th>alamat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
            <?php foreach($daftar_user as $user) : ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user->nik; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->nama; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->tempat_lahir; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->tanggal_lahir; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->umur; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->status; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->jenis_kelamin; ?></td>        
        <td><?php echo $user->alamat; ?></td>
        </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nik</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Tempat Lahir</th>
            <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
        <th>Umur</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
            <th>alamat</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear daftar_user is not defined inside the code which you posted to view